# parsing Google maps with filter

Tags: java, android, google-geocoder

I'm new to building applications (so far made ​​only one application ) . The question is - can not figure out whether it is possible to make parsing Google maps ? For example user clicks a button and he at around 100 yards displayed cafe . that is, Google determines the location of the user and is recognized all around the cafe (not on the map and the text on the page ) . Now try to understand how the geocoder, but not sure that I was going in the right direction . Are there any ideas what the library is connected properly and work with her?

Answer (score 0):

I hardly understand your question, however, I should mention that there are two versions of google maps API for android at the moment, and those versions differ significantly. It's really sensible to use API v2.

You can find good tutorials on this topic, one is [here](http://www.startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/306-urok-139-google-maps-sozdanie-i-nastrojka-proekta-karta-kamera-sobytija.html), notice that russian and english versions of site are available.

> whether it is possible to make parsing Google maps

If you mean getting geo coordinates on click event you can find OnMapClickListener class useful, see the tutorial above for help.